# making cli python code compatible with package manager

Tags: python, pip, package

We have a bunch of code that was thrown together horribly for ad-hoc local execution.  I have started to refactor it, and would like to do this in stages.

As a first step, I would like to put our code into a nice package structure:

```
Project/
|
|-- project/
|   |-- code/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- horribleness_with_importables_but_also__main__.py
|   |   |-- more_horribleness.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README.md
```

As such, I can do the appropriate things in `setup.py` and `__init__.py` so that `$ pip install git+[my_project]` works as expected and makes `from project.more_horribleness import *` work as expected.

However, I've now changed all of my local imports to be relative, and put imports into `__init__.py`s and what have you to make the pip thing work... so to avoid any major problems, for now, I would ALSO like to be able to git clone the repo and call, somehow, `$ python horribleness_with_importables_but_also__main__.py` and have it work as previously.  Is there a nice way to run my python `if __name__ == "__main__":`s from within my newfound pip package structure?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your package is pure Python, the critical part is that

```
/path/to/Project
```

is in the Python path, either via the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or a manipulation of `sys.path`. However, this is not the solution I would recommend. As you have taken the care to make your package pip-installable I suggest

1. Use `pip install --user -e .`: this will symlink your project in `~/.local/lib/pythonVERSION/site-packages` but edits to your project are taken into account.
2. Move the main function in `project/__main__.py` so that it can be executed from the command-line as `python -m project` *or* use the `console_scripts` option to have your executable installed in your `PATH` when installing https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#console-scripts